# Custom post type loop

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I need some guidance on this script.

I'm working on a custom post type loop but I'm stuck on how to convert this static html to a php loop

```
<?php 
    $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
    $count =0;
?>
<!--Text Sliders-->
<div class="ps-contentwrapper">
    <?php if ( $loop ) : 

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'tagproject' );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
    $links = array();

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
    {
        $links[] = $term->name;
    }
    $links = str_replace(' ', '-', $links); 
    $tax = join( " ", $links );     
else :  
    $tax = '';  
endif;
?>
    <?php $infos = get_post_custom_values('_url'); ?>
    <div class="ps-content">
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div><!--end of ps-content-->


</div><!-- /ps-contentwrapper -->

<!--Image Sliders-->
<div class="ps-slidewrapper">

    <div class="ps-slides">
        <?php
            $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
        ?>
        <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $url; ?>);"></div>
    </div>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <nav>
        <a href="#" class="ps-prev" style="background-image: url(images/home/1.jpg);"></a>
        <a href="#" class="ps-next" style="background-image: url(images/home/2.jpg);"></a>
    </nav>
```

Here is the [tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/01/vertical-showcase-slider-with-jquery-and-css-transitions/comment-page-1/#comments) I'm trying to convert. [Demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/VerticalShowcaseSlider/).

What I'm trying to figure out is how to line up everything dynamically. If someone can point me to the right direction I appreciate it.

My [version](http://cakeandconfetti.mmidevsite2.com/test/) of it with the current code I pasted above.

EDIT: Here is my code now after a bit of research. Now I'm trying to figure out how I can match the featured image to the appropriate post as it cycles through in this script. The div tag that echos the url needs to loop as many times the loop does and cycle appropriately.

```
<div class="ps-slides">
                    <?php
                        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
                    ?>
                    <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $url; ?>);"></div>
                </div><!--end of ps-slides-->
```

Full code below:

```
<div class="ps-contentwrapper">
                <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="ps-content">
                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>                      
                        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>             
                    </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>  
                    <?php endif; ?>             
            </div><!--end of contentwrapper-->
            <!--Image Sliders-->
            <div class="ps-slidewrapper">
                <div class="ps-slides">
                    <?php
                        $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
                    ?>
                    <div style="background-image: url(<?php echo $url; ?>);"></div>
                </div><!--end of ps-slides-->
                <nav>
                     <?php
                        $prev_post = get_previous_post(); 
                        $id = $prev_post->ID ;
                        $permalink = get_permalink( $id );
                        $prev_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($id) );
                        ?>
                            <a href="#" class="ps-prev" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $prev_url; ?>);"></a>
                        <?php 
                            $next_post = get_next_post();
                            $nid = $next_post->ID ;
                            $permalink = get_permalink($nid);
                            $next_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($nid) );
                        ?>
                        <a href="#" class="ps-next" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $next_url; ?>);"></a>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> use code for your previous next post image url:

```
<?php
    $prev_post = get_previous_post(); 
    $id = $prev_post->ID ;
    $permalink = get_permalink( $id );
    $prev_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($id) );
?>
<a href="#" class="ps-prev" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $prev_url; ?>);"></a>

<?php 
    $next_post = get_next_post();
    $nid = $next_post->ID ;
    $permalink = get_permalink($nid);
    $next_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($nid) );
?>
<a href="#" class="ps-next" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $next_url; ?>);"></a>
```

Comment: Awesome. I been following this tutorial and yours saved me so much time. Thanks.

Comment: after click on next and previous button your code like:
<div style="background-image: url(&quot;http://cakeandconfetti.mmidevsite2.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/1.jpg&quot;); top: 100%; z-index: 1;" class=""></div>
but your style in top:0 zindex:999 is set so this problem is solved.
<div style="background-image: url("images/1.jpg"); top: 0px; z-index: 999;" class=""></div>